# How can I get ddl of granted objects in SYBASE ASE 15.5?

Tags: java, oracle, command, sap-ase

I am trying to create a application that will export ddl for the given schema.

I created sample in java using ddlgen command. In which, I can get ddl for all objects for the schema of logged.
Command is:

```
java -cp "C:/Users/admin/Desktop/lib/jconn4.jar;C:/Users/admin/Desktop/lib/dsparser.jar;C:/Users/admin/Desktop/lib/DDLGen.jar" com.sybase.ddlgen.DDLGenerator -Usybase1 -Psybase1 -Sserver-name  -Ddatbase1  -Ooutput.sql
```

In the above command I need do give for UserName and Password.

Now I have second another user sybase2, who is a grantee and sybase1 user grants access of all objects to sybase2 user. Here I want get ddl of sybase1 user from the sybase2 user's account.

Same thing I have done in oracle where we have two users user1 and user2 . The user1 grant all permission to access all objects to user2. 
I can successfully getList of all granted objects.

**Query:-**

```
select object_name from dba_objects where owner = 'user1';
```

and after that using **get_ddl** functions, I am getting ddl of all objects.

The above method of ddlgen, I did not find a way to pass schema name, for which I want to get ddl.

Is ddlgen does not support this ? 
If not then please suggest us other way to get ddl for the given schema.

**We also do not found 'How to create new schema except 'dbo' ?'**

Comment: Hi, Don't forget to upvote/accept helpful answers.  :?)

Answer (score 0):

SAP/Sybase ASE does not use the Oracle/Microsoft implementation of schemas.

You can find the owners of database objects by joining `sysobjects` and `sysusers`

```
SELECT db_name()
     , su.name
     , so.type
     , so.name
 FROM sysusers su, sysobjects so
WHERE su.uid = so.uid
 AND su.name = "[name of user you are looking for]"
```